# T-SQL Formatting Nested JSON Output

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I am using SQL Server 2019. My data has the overlapping values for all rows except 2. I would to be able to flatten this table and output it as JSON.

**Schema**

---

```
CREATE TABLE student_data(
     first_name varchar(50),
     last_name varchar(50),
     grade int,
     ID int,
     subject varchar(50),
     teacher varchar(50)
);


INSERT INTO student_data
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 0, 1000, 'Home Room', 'Parker, Peter')
      ,('John', 'Doe', 0, 1000, 'Math', 'Quest, Jonny')
      ,('John', 'Doe', 0, 1000, 'Reading', 'Gordon, Flash')
      ,('John', 'Doe', 0, 1000, 'History', 'Banner, Bruce')
      ,('John', 'Doe', 0, 1000, 'Science', 'Kent, Clark')
      ,('Jane', 'Doe', 0, 2000, 'Home Room', 'Parker, Peter')
      ,('Jane', 'Doe', 0, 2000, 'Math', 'Quest, Jonny')
      ,('Jane', 'Doe', 0, 2000, 'Reading', 'Gordon, Flash')
      ,('Jane', 'Doe', 0, 2000, 'History', 'Banner, Bruce')
      ,('Jane', 'Doe', 0, 2000, 'Science', 'Kent, Clark');
```

**Current Output**

---

```
SELECT *
FROM student_data
WHERE ID=1000;
```

| first_name | last_name | grade | ID | subject | teacher |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Doe | 0 | 1000 | Home Room | Parker, Peter |
| John | Doe | 0 | 1000 | Math | Quest, Jonny |
| John | Doe | 0 | 1000 | Reading | Gordon, Flash |
| John | Doe | 0 | 1000 | History | Banner, Bruce |
| John | Doe | 0 | 1000 | Science | Kent, Clark |

```
SELECT *
FROM student_data
WHERE ID=1000
FOR JSON AUTO;
```

```
[
    {"first_name":"John",
    "last_name":"Doe",
    "grade":0,
    "ID":1000,
    "subject":"Home Room",
    "teacher":"Parker, Peter"},
    {"first_name":"John",
    "last_name":"Doe",
    "grade":0,
    "ID":1000,
    "subject":"Math",
    "teacher":"Quest, Jonny"},
    {"first_name":"John",
    "last_name":"Doe",
    "grade":0,
    "ID":1000,
    "subject":"Reading",
    "teacher":"Gordon, Flash"},
    {"first_name":"John",
    "last_name":"Doe",
    "grade":0,"ID":1000,
    "subject":"History",
    "teacher":"Banner, Bruce"},
    {"first_name":"John",
    "last_name":"Doe",
    "grade":0,
    "ID":1000,
    "subject":"Science",
    "teacher":"Kent, Clark"}
]
```

**Desired Output**

---

```
{"first_name":"John",
"last_name":"Doe",
"grade":0,
"ID":1000,
"Home Room":{"teacher":"Parker, Peter"},
"Math":{"teacher":"Quest, Jonny"},
"Reading":{"teacher":"Gordon, Flash"},
"History":{"teacher":"Banner, Bruce"},
"Science":{"teacher":"Kent, Clark"}
}
```

Comment: Json is built around name/value pairs.  Putting values into names is bad form, and makes the JSON hard to process and map to a database table or a Javascript object.

Comment: How can we provide query when we have no data to run it on?!? Please provide queries to create the relevant tables and insert sample data to all tables + please provide the expected result which you want to get according to the sample data.

Comment: If you can preproduce the source issue which you have with simple scenario (maybe single table or two, then please simplifies the scenario so we will focus on the issue.